# Long executing script rerun itself after 4 minutes?

Tags: php, laravel

I am in WTF mode now and cant realize where my problem is comming from.

I have Laravel system installed. I run the URL which is pointing to a controller. This controller starts and do its work normally! BUT , every time after 4 minutes .. the same code is executed again - Its like i refreshed the page.

The "start" function is out of any foreach or loop , no continue; or break.

```
function start(){

   //Write in the log

   foreach(){
      //Call to different functions
   }

   //End log
}
```

If i use info which cause ther script to run less than 4 minutes - everything end well:

Start log

...

End log

But if i use data , which runs the script longer than 4 minutes:

Start log
...
...
Start log (again)

The script reruns itself after 4 minutes .... WHY? Please help!

Comment: max runtime + auto-restart-on-failure?

Comment: max runtime is set to 3600 sec, memory peak is 177 from 512 MB. 
Also - NO input data at all. And i dont know where auto-restart-on-failure option is set. php.ini ?

Comment: If when there's no data to iterate with the `foreach` you get what you expect, but when there's data you get a second call to the controller method, then something might be happening inside the loop. What does "__Call to different functions__" mean? What functions and what do they do? They may well be the cause of your problem, so please give more details, or even better post that code.